# when i run my code No qualifying bean of type 'com.temp.dao.TempDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

Tags: java, spring, ejb

my spring code is below. please any one explain what is wrong in my code.

TempImpl.class

```
 @Component
 @Transactional
public class tempImpl{
        @Autowired
         private TempController tempController;

        public void temp_1(){
         String status = tempController.saveTemp1();
       }
}
```

TempController.class

```
 @Component
 public class TempController{
         @Autowired
         private TempDao tempDao;

        public void saveTemp1(){
         String status = tempDao.saveTemp1();
       }
}
```

TempDao.class

```
@Component
 public class TempDao{
        public void saveTemp1(){
        TempEntity   tempEntity     =  new TempEntity();
    tempEntity.seTemp1Value("hello");
       }
}
```

xml config file is

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:cache="http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache"
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache http://www.springframework.org/schema/cache/spring-cache.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd">



<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.temp.dao" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.temp.service" />
<context:component-scan base-package="com.temp.controller" />



<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" proxy-target-class="true"/>
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.WebLogicJtaTransactionManager"/>

<!-- For Struts Action Class -->
<bean name="/saveTestAction" class="com.temp.tempAction" />


</beans>
```

when my code comes Dao class and while executing tempEntity.seTemp1Value("hello"); this line

```
 No qualifying bean of type 'com.temp.dao.TempDao' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: 
 {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
```

Comment: Please add your configuration. Have you enabled component scanning?

Comment: yes, <context:component-scan base-package="com.temp.dao" /> this is i add

Comment: why there are () in front of class name. Class signature in java should not be like method.

Comment: now it is modified.

Comment: Also TempController and tempImpl class are in same base package or different one?. Your base package should be topmost package so it can autowire all dependencies.

Comment: all are different packages . but i used component scan in all packages. but still i have that error.

Comment: update you config class.